# AnyLogic: Does anyone know what "int approximationOrder" in the constructor of a table function stands for?

Tags: anylogic

I want to use the constructor of an AnyLogic TableFunction, but I do not know what `int approximationOrder` stands for. The constructor without it is labeled as deprecated. Can anyone help?

Comment: please provide full description of this API no jest name of parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int approximationOrder: the order (1, 2, 3...) of the approximation polynomial if the INTERPOLATION_APPROXIMATION mode is selected`

If you do not set your `InterpolationType` to `INTERPOLATION_APPROXIMATION` then it does not matter what you choose here.

For example:

```
TableFunction x = new TableFunction(
    new double[]{1,2,3,4,5},
    new double[]{1,2,1,2,2},
    TableFunction.InterpolationType.INTERPOLATION_LINEAR,
    1, //approximationOrder makes no impact as we will not be using it
    TableFunction.OUTOFRANGE_ERROR,
    999.0
);
```

It is this parameter you see when you select your interpolation to approximation

[image]

What version of AnyLogic are you using? The latest version has this documented

Comment: So what value should I take for approximationOrder when I just want to use the default settings? I have the newest AnyLogic University Version.

Comment: See my updated answer. It will not be used unless you choose the interpolation type to use use the Interpolation_Approximation